# PHP version issue

Tags: views

I have 4 Drupal 7.40 sites the one main site I want to upgrade to Drupal 8. The 3 sites use php v. 5.4 and Drupal 8 needs php 5.5.19 minimum and 5.6 recomended. My shared server has php 5.4 and 5.6.

When I changed the php version to 5.6 the three sites which are **sitename.com** domains working but can not login to them and the one site which is **sitename.com.pk** is totaly gone.

Any idea how to fix this issue? Or can I use php 5.6 for my main site and 5.4 on other domains on same shared hosting server?

Comment: What do you mean by "can not log in"? Any specific error? White screen? PHP errors? Does anything get logged?

Comment: Each of those domains should have a server log whose contents may help in solving the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access, and listing all the possible causes hoping to guess what happened in your case is outside the purpose of this site.

Comment: `Release candidates are not supported for production sites, but they are intended for widespread testing in preparation for the upcoming stable release.` Don't upgrade to 8 yet!!!

Comment: @steven when i change php version from 5.4 to 5.6 and refresh site it automatically logouts and the login screen shows a white screen

Comment: I was searching internet for this issue and found the answer.   If you set the php version to 5.4 it will save a new php.ini file in the public_html folder.  You could then copy that to the folder that you want to use php5.4 on and then set the php version back to 5.6.  You'll need a copy of the php.ini 5.6 in each folder that you want to use it for and a .htaccess rule at the beginning of the file directing that folder to use the php version you want.

Comment: for the folders you want to use php 5.6 put this at the top of the .htaccess files

# Use PHPBETA as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpbeta .php

for the folder you need 5.4 use this 

# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

and then of course make sure to copy the php.ini file for 5.4 to that folder, and the php.ini file for 5.6 to the other folders.